# Just found an answer to my own question. What to do?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette, self-answer

I posted a question.  After messing around on my machine for about an hour, I found a solution.  Would it be more appropriate to remove the question, or to add the answer to it just to save some other poor idiot the trouble I went through?

Re: The duplicate.  I was asking in a specific situation whether it is more appropriate to give an answer or delete a question to which I was able to find an answer *soon* after asking.  I see this as being somewhat different from the situation of the other question.

Comment: *"I see this as being somewhat different from the situation of the other question."* - No it isn't. It doesn't matter when you found the answer, you can answer your own question. That's what the existing answer tells you.

Comment: That's what the 'answer your own question' button is for.

Comment: The only reason not to post an answer would be if the solution you found suggests that it's a bad question (say, if it was a simple typo and the answer is unlikely to be useful to others). If you decide a question you've posted is a bad one, you can always delete it for that reason. If it was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45464027/827263), I see you've already posted an answer. The question and the answer have each gotten one upvote, so I presume it's useful to someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's preferable to provide an answer to your own question than to delete an ontopic i.e. useful question.

[Self Answers are encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

There's also the issue of deleting content on the site, as we agree to the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal)

> **3. Subscriber Content**
>
> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the
>   Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange
>   under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. .../...

So technically the content we post is not ours to delete alone.

Also - note worthy is deleting and posting too many low quality questions can lead to a [Question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).